# Does setDefaultHighRepJobPolicyUnappliedJobPercentage(100) really work?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

According to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting#Writing_HRD_Datastore_Tests, "If your app uses the High Replication Datastore (HRD), you may want to write tests that verify your application's behavior in the face of eventual consistency. LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig exposes options that make this easy."  You're supposed to set `setDefaultHighRepJobPolicyUnappliedJobPercentage(100)` and then, "By setting the unapplied job percentage to 100, we are instructing the local datastore to operate with the maximum amount of eventual consistency. Maximum eventual consistency means writes will commit but always fail to apply, so global (non-ancestor) queries will consistently fail to see changes."

However, I don't think `setDefaultHighRepJobPolicyUnappliedJobPercentage(100)` works.

If it did, then my test case below, `testEventualConsistency()` should pass but it it fails on the second assertion.  On the first assertion, I read back an object I've saved using an Objectify ancestor() query.  It works as documented because the object is retrieved.  However, the second assertion fails.  In that assertion I've also read back the object I've saved but I haven't used an Objectify ancestor() query so it shouldn't retrieve anything because I've specified that no jobs should complete (i.e. the `setDefaultHighRepJobPolicyUnappliedJobPercentage(100)` setting).

**EventualConsistencyTest Test Case**

```
import static com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService.begin;
import static com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService.ofy;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalServiceTestHelper;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService;
import com.googlecode.objectify.Ref;
import com.googlecode.objectify.util.Closeable;
import com.netbase.followerdownloader.model.DownloadTask;
import com.netbase.followerdownloader.model.User;

public class EventualConsistencyTest {
    private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
            new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig()
                .setDefaultHighRepJobPolicyUnappliedJobPercentage(100));    

    @Test
    public void testEventualConsistency() {
        helper.setUp();
        ObjectifyRegistrar.registerDataModel();

        User user = new User();
        user.id = 1L;
        Closeable closeable1 = begin();
        ofy().save().entity(user);
        closeable1.close();

        Closeable closeable2 = begin();
        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
        downloadTask.owner = Ref.create(user);
        ofy().save().entity(downloadTask);
        closeable2.close();

        Closeable closeable3 = ObjectifyService.begin();
        List<DownloadTask> downloadTasks1 = ofy().load().type(DownloadTask.class).ancestor(user).list();
        assertThat(downloadTasks1.size(), equalTo(1));
        closeable3.close();

        Closeable closeable4 = ObjectifyService.begin();
        List<DownloadTask> downloadTasks2 = ofy().load().type(DownloadTask.class).list();
        assertThat(downloadTasks2.size(), equalTo(0));  //  THIS SHOULD PASS IF setDefaultHighRepJobPolicyUnappliedJobPercentage(100) WORKED
        closeable4.close();

        helper.tearDown();
    }

}
```

**User Definition**

```
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id;

@Entity
public class User {
    @Id public Long id;

    public User () {

    }
}
```

**DownloadTask Definition**

```
import com.googlecode.objectify.Ref;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Parent;

@Entity
public class DownloadTask {
    @Id public Long id;

    @Parent public Ref<User> owner;

    public DownloadTask() {

    }
}
```

*Environment:*

- appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.17.jar
- appengine-testing-1.9.17.jar
- appengine-api-stubs-1.9.17.jar
- junit-4.11.jar
- objectify-5.1.3.jar

In case I missed anything else important, here is a more exhaustive list:

[image: Environment]

***My questions are:***

1. Is `setDefaultHighRepJobPolicyUnappliedJobPercentage(100)` broken?
2. Does `setDefaultHighRepJobPolicyUnappliedJobPercentage(100)` not really work as documented?  Does it in fact apply the job even though the documentation says it's not supposed to?
3. Is the value passed to `setDefaultHighRepJobPolicyUnappliedJobPercentage()` really supposed to be `100` and not maybe let's say, `1.0f`?
4. Do Objectify ancestor queries not really work as documented?

Comment: You may have run afoul of the observation "please keep in mind that the local High Replication read consistency model is an approximation of the production High Replication read consistency model, not an exact replica. In the local environment, performing a get() of an Entity that belongs to an entity group with an unapplied write will always make the results of the unapplied write visible to subsequent global queries. In production this is not the case." at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting#Java_Writing_High_Replication_Datastore_tests

Comment: You can avoid your tests influencing each other, and in particular, interfering w/each other in this way, by using separate test methods rather than successive operations within a single test method.

Comment: Thank you @AlexMartelli. If I understand what you're saying, the interference is my Objectify ancestor query that is causing my non-ancestor query to see an object that I thought it shouldn't be able to see. Does that mean an Objectify ancestor query is the same as a "get() of an Entity that belongs to an entity group" that's mentioned in link you provided and a non-ancestor query is a "global query".

Comment: I'm no Objectify guru, but it seems to me that inevitably, under the hood, it (or any other wrapper around the gae-datastore) must issue low-level `get` requests -- either with ancestors (==entity groups) or without (==global).

Comment: @AlexMartelli, thank you. I tried something that supports your theory. I removed the ancestor query (==entity group get request) and the non-ancestor query (==global query) acted as expected--i.e. the `assertThat(downloadTasks2.size(), equalTo(0));` passed.  If you want to write an answer referencing "In the local environment, performing a get() of an Entity that belongs to an entity group with an unapplied write will always make the results of the unapplied write visible to subsequent global queries." I will accept your answer.

Comment: I've now posted these observation as an answer, as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is explained by an observation at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting#Java_Writing_High_Replication_Datastore_tests :
"In the local environment, performing a get() of an Entity that belongs to an entity group with an unapplied write will always make the results of the unapplied write visible to subsequent global queries."

In this contect, this means the ancestor-query:

```
List<DownloadTask> downloadTasks1 = ofy().load().type(DownloadTask.class).ancestor(user).list();
```

which internally "performs a `get()` of an `Entity` that belongs to an entity group with an unapplied write" influences the behavior of the immediately-following global query:

```
List<DownloadTask> downloadTasks2 = ofy().load().type(DownloadTask.class).list();
```

To avoid your tests influencing each other, and in particular, interfering w/each other in this way, it's best to use a separate method per operation under test (each with all the needed setup and teardown parts), rather than having successive operations-under-test within a single test method.

Comment: Thanks again @AlexMartelli.  Happy New Year.